# How can I follow input links in auctex

Tags: emacs, auctex

Is it possible to do the following with AucTeX:

Suppose you have a master file (`master.tex`) like:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
   \input{fileA}
   \input{fileB}
\end{document}
```

and for example `fileA.tex` looks like:

```
Some text

%% Local Variables:
%% coding: utf-8
%% TeX-master: "master.tex"
%% End:
```

Now I am looking for an easy way to navigate between the master and input files, so I need the following:

1. Click (with modifier) on `\input{fileA}` in the master file to open `fileA.tex` or just switch to its buffer if it exists. Alternatively to clicking: move point to `fileA` an press some key sequence to do the same.
2. When you are `fileA.tex`: Press a key sequence to open the master file or just switch to its buffer if it exists and move the point to the line `\input{fileA}`.

Same with `\include` instead of `\input`.

So, how can I do this or something similar in AucTeX?

Comment: Have a look at `find-file-at-point` for question 1. Question 2 would require some elisp hacks with `TeX-master` and `search-forward`, and you would have to be very careful for example if you inadvertently input the same file twice (even in a comment). As an out-of-the-box solution, you can check `reftex`, and in particular its table of contents feature (`C-c =`). In that table of contents, pressing `F` will show the file boundaries, allowing you to perform the kind of navigation you request.

Comment: To find the master file I use `(find-file (TeX-master-file t nil t))`.